# how to get the pc register for any thread on Linux?

Tags: assembly

My debug thread will monitor the memory usage. When it finds the inconsistency situation it will generate a coredump.

As I found, the coredump is not very accurate (looks a bit later than the moment the problem happened, because I need to do some cleanup in the debug thread before `abort()`).

I want to record the exact `%pc` register of the thread val at that time, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a 'recent' `%pc` --*program counter*-- (also know as `%ip` *instruction pointer*) is to save the state of your process with [`makecontext`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/makecontext.html)

```
void makecontext(ucontext_t *ucp, void (*func)(), int argc, ...);
```

and read the right value in the buffer: `REG_EIP` as defined in `sys/ucontext.h`

```
context.uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EIP];
```

Please note that the data structure is obviously machine-dependent, and for instance, if you were using a SPARC, the `%ip` would have been stored in `REG_RIP`

--

as far as I know, there is no way to read this value for all the threads, you'll have to read the `%pc` on each of them, and gather manually your data.

Comment: quoted:
as far as I know, there is no way to read this value for all the threads, you'll have to read the %pc on each of them, and gather manually your data.

my idea is to use a dedicated thread to monitor memory, it will generate coredump or record the $pc when it finds memory changed.but sounds that I can not do that?

is there another good way to monitor the memory(especially for memory overwrite), as I can't use valgrind or purify (they are too heavy in my environment).

thanks a lot!

Comment: @jon: I don't really understand how you want to use your thread to monitor memory changes, maybe you can update the question with further details ?